# Running a command with < and &>

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I was wondering if someone could explain what the '<' and the '&>' mean in this statement here.

```
./pa1 < test.lig &> test.out
```

Here is the code for the frontend of the C program. This is an update to show how I am reading the command line arguments to supply to the program for the input output operations.

```
#include "tokens.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern FILE *yyin;
extern FILE *yyout;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc == 3){
        printf("Input file = %s\n", argv[1]);
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        yyout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if (yyin == 0 || yyout == 0) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            yyin = stdin;
            exit(0);
        }else{
            fprintf(yyout, "File %s opened!\n", argv[1]);
        }
    }else{
        exit(1);
    }

    //Variables
    /*
        Integers
            1) tokenCount - Counts the number of tokens present in the file. 
            2) lexReturnToken - Checks to see if it is a valid token (not 999 according to tokens.h) 
                and then checks to see if it is a bracket, parentheses or curly so proper checks may be called.
     */
    int tokenCount = 0, lexReturnToken;

    //Standard Output Information
    while(1){
        lexReturnToken = yylex();
        if(lexReturnToken > 0){
            //Token Count
            if(lexReturnToken != 999){
                tokenCount++;
            }//else{

               // }
            //}
        }else{
            printf("Total tokens: %d\n", tokenCount);
            break;
        }
    }

        //Bool Main Detection (preceded by function)
        //Bool Bracket, Parentheses, Curly Match

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `test.lig &>` not `test.lig >&` ?

Comment: The documentation at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection covers this in detail.

Comment: Thank you for providing the source -- that makes the problem entirely obvious.

Comment: @haccks, `&>` is an extension available in bash and others for redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirections are setting up stdin and stdout, but your program opens files named on the command line -- so it isn't *using* stdin and stdout.

When you run `./pa1 <test.lig &>test.out`, the `<test.lig` and `&>test.out` redirections are parsed as commands to the shell -- so they aren't included in your argv, which only contains `{"./pa1", NULL}`.

If you want the redirections to work, then when `argc` shows that no arguments have been provided, ensure that you proceed with `yyin` as `stdin` and `yyout` as `stdout`, instead of calling `exit(1)` as you currently do.

Answer (score 1):

`<` is accepting input from a file, in this case sending anything in `test.lig` to `pa1`. As you might expect `>` is redirecting output, sending anything you'd normally see outputed from `pa1` on the screen to the file `test.out`.

`&>` is sending both standard output AND errors to test.out, without it any errors would still show up in your terminal and not pollute the output file.

Answer (score 0):

it means that the input of ./pa1 program is in the test.lig file and the output will be the test.out file

Comment: So that affects my argc and agrv? Cause if I run the program without them it works just fine.

Comment: @pmac89 no impact on argc and argv at all. It changes where your stdin and stdout file descriptors go to.

Comment: no impact. It only changes the output and the input. It will takes the argv from the test.lig file.

Comment: Well when I run it with that it does not output anything to my out file.

Comment: @pmac89, how are we supposed to speak to how a tool we've never seen is supposed to behave? We can tell you, and accurately, what a given command line does, but we can't tell you if, for instance, it checks whether its output is a file instead of a TTY and changes its behavior in that case.

Comment: If it's the same result than it the file will not change because it will be overridden with the same content

Comment: Also, I know it is pointing the stdout to the file but printf statements don't work, only when I do fprintf. (Note this is only for when I do it ./pa1 test.liger test.out

Comment: @pmac89, again, I don't know how you expect anyone to tell you anything more without seeing the program's source. We answered your questions about what the redirections do; why your program behaves unexpectedly when those redirections are in place is your problem now.

Comment: I've updated it with the source code.

Comment: It should redirect the output weather its fprintf(stdout) or with printf()

Comment: @pmac89, thank you; I've added an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the contents of file test.lig and pass it as input to ./pa1, then push the output to test.out.

The &> tells it to pipe both stdout and stderr to the file instead of just stdout.

Comment: "pass it as input" is unclear, when the problem is that the program expects input files to be passed as separate command-line arguments.